# Detecting process crashes with New Relic in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, newrelic

How do you get New Relic to log errors which crash the process using their New Relic application monitoring? The key things I'm trying to accomplish are to have **errors which crash the process still get logged** and some way to **filter to these errors on the dashboard**.

Here's my understanding so far:

1. New Relic transmits data to their cloud every minute. In the event a `uncaughtException` occurs, this will result in all of the data currently waiting to be transmitted to be lost.
2. There is a `newrelic.noticeError()` which is supposed to take a second argument allowing you to pass custom parameters with an error. New relic gets the error, but not the custom parameters.

Simple Example:

```
var newrelic = require("newrelic");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/softFail/", function(req, res) {
    res.send(500, "softFail");
});

app.get("/hardFail/", function(req, res) {
    setImmediate(function() {
        throw new Error("I failed");
    });
});

app.listen(80);

process.on("uncaughtException", function(err) {
    console.error("Uncaught Exception");
    console.error(err.stack);
    newrelic.addCustomParameter("crash", "true");
    newrelic.noticeError(err);
    console.log("sending errors to New Relic");
    newrelic.agent.harvest(function() {
        console.log("send complete, crashing process");
        process.exit(1);
    });
});
```

Using that block of code if I call /hardFail/ I'm able to get New Relic to at least log the error. Without the `uncaughtException` handler I don't get anything to New Relic. The issue is that I can't differentiate between the errors which crash the process, and normal HTTP 500 errors.

Here's something things I've tried:

1. If I attempt to add `{ crash : true }` to the `noticeError` call it doesn't seem to have any affect.
2. I've tried to do `domain` instead of `process.on`, that doesn't change the situation.
3. If I attempt to alter the `name` of the error, such as `err.name = "CrashError"` then the error doesn't get transmitted at all.
4. If I create a custom error type, and then new that, and copy the stack trace on to it, it still reports as type `Error` rather than the `prototype.name` of my new error type.

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the call to `harvest`, you helped me a lot!

Comment: Is there a solution? How did you get it to work?

Comment: Unfortunately we were never able to find a solution for it. We've actually stopped using Newrelic's application monitoring in favor of Loggly. It's made error logging and process logging a lot easier.

Comment: I've reported a similar issue to the `node-newrelic` team: https://github.com/newrelic/node-newrelic/issues/1561